# Huh? Can anyone explain why I'd care about the previous page?

Tags: browser-addons, internet-explorer-8, activex, citrix

So this is one of the more bizarre messages I've seen.  Going to a web page to get access to a remote session via Citrix:

"The previous webpage might require the following add-on: ... Click here to allow it to run"

First, why would that be showing up on the current page?  What's going to happen if I allow it to run?

Comment: Does the actual error message say `...`?

Comment: That's an exact quote, which is why it's so strange.

Answer (score 1):

I might be off base here, but a lot of remote software, logmein.com for instance, requires the use of plugins for efficient and fast remote access.  Referring to the previous page would make sense if either

a) the page to access your remote site was redirected to the error page when the plugin was found to be missing,

or

b) if the message was shown on a pop-up or page/alert header that loaded on top of the page that you wanted to see.

If the plugin is from Citrix (as it would be if you were trying to use go2mypc), you should be safe installing it.  It will just make the remote access process work a little more smoothly.